# WordPress - Multiple Authors to a custom post

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the plugin WP Job Manager in WordPress where users can post job listings. In larger companies, several users within the company want to be able to see job listing posted from their company and thereby see the applications received. In the database, the user who posts the post will have their id in "post_author" column.

My questions is how is it possible to attach multiple users to a post manually? My first through was to use like an array of user id's in "post_author" this won't work I see. I've used co-author plugins without success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found answer to the problem.

Comment: No.. Ended up without this feature